# Jenkins: Failed To Connect to Git Repository

Tags: git, jenkins

Hope someone can help out with this. We have Jenkins connected to our git repository through alternative credentials. We are not using SSH, so it's pretty basic stuff here. Everything was working fine until 9PM last night when Jenkins could no longer access our repository. Very strange since nobody has touched Jenkins or visual studio in some time. When the failure alerts came in, I began to update Jenkins and it's plugins. This made no change. I made sure that the alternative credentials are the same as what's in the Jenkins dashboard. I confirmed the service account we are using does have access to the repository. But this is what I continue to see:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe ls-remote -h https://prod1.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://prod1.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts/'
```

[image: jenkins fails to authenticate]

Regarless if I change the credentials to the alternative, I get the same error. On the master, I try to connect to the repository again through git bash, and I receive this:

```
$ git.exe ls-remote -h https://prod1.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts HEAD

Username for 'https://prod1.visualstudio.com': vsts-svc@work.com
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://prod1.visualstudio.com/_git/prodscripts/'
```

[image: git bash authentication failure]

Any help would be appreicated. I'm not too savvy with this, and have inherrited the system. I'm  not too sure where to go about this. It looks like a simple fix, but obviously matching the creds up between git and jenkins is not working.

Comment: so this seems to be rather a problem with your account on visualstudio.com, right?

Comment: not sure. I can login to visualstudio.com using that account with no issue and the account is an admin. I did open a support ticket with them as well though.

Comment: Could it be something about ssl certificates? Is your git up-to-date? Unfortunately this seems not to be very reproducible / solvable here..

Comment: Yeah, so it seems. I did update git to the most up to date version as well on both the master and slave server. I'm baffled how this happened, especially since it was untouched during this time. I don't get any SSL errors either.

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `GIT_TRACE=1`, then you'll get some extra debug info about what exactly git is doing

Answer (score 0):

I asked the Jenkins gods over on their site and were able to resolve the issue pretty quickly. Apparently, Visual Studio sometimes blocks alternative credentials from being used due to security issues. They recommended that I try using a personal access token instead. Once I set one up and changed the credentials in Jenkins, we were back to normal. I'm sure there is a place that would tell me if alternative creds were blocked, but I did not find it. Another caveat is that the token is only valid for a max of one year, so you will have to remind yourself to change it a year from now.